# .htaccess (запрет выполнения скриптов в папке вне корня сайта)

Tags: .htaccess

VPS (ubuntu16.04) Структура папок такая: /var/www/site/public_html (корень сайта) и /var/www/site/filestorage (для загрузки картинок). В /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site.conf переопределение правил локальными файлами .htaccess разрешено:
(Directory /var/www/site)
    AllowOverride All
(/Directory).

Пытаюсь запретить выполнение скриптов в папке для загрузки фото (установить php_flag engine off).
В /var/www/site/public_html/.htaccess действует. В /var/www/site/filestorage/ свой файл .htaccess НЕ действует. 
Права доступа к папке /var/www/site/filestorage и на файл в ней .htaccess для сервера (www-data): rwx. Проверяю следующим образом: устанавливаю в этом файле .htaccess новое значение директивы php_value precision 15 (по умолчанию оно равно 14) и смотрю текущее значение echo ini_get('precision'); вызываемое из файла test.php в одной из подпапок /var/www/site/filestorage, а также смотрю выполняется ли код php (echo). Новое значение не устанавливается, код php выполняется. Третий день перебираю комбинации настроек и ничерта не получается.

P.S: добавил "ошибку синтаксиса" в /var/www/site/filestorage/.htaccess (набор случайных символов), картинки перестали подгружаться на сайте, в error.log apache2 пишет о ошибке синтаксиса (/var/www/site/filestorage/.htaccess: Invalid command 'AHHH', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration)

Comment: куда смотрит сервер? в site или site/public_html?

Comment: DocumentRoot /var/www/site/public_html

Comment: .htaccess, лежащий в site не читается, т.к. сервер смотрит в public_html + filestorage не доступен, т.к. находится вне public_html (только если не настроен еще один хост или нет симлинка, лежащего внутри public_html)

Comment: Делал симлинк в public_html на filestorage кстати, эффекта никакого. Еще один хост не настроен.  Файл test.php инклудится из основного скрипта (и выполняется), синтаксис htaccess проверяется сервером, но инструкции в нем не учитываются, так получается? а есть ли тогда другой способ запретить интерпретатору php выполнять код в соседней папке от корневой?

Comment: Так-то напрашивающееся решение: папку для загрузки файлов делать вне корня сайта , и запрет выполнения скриптов в ней. Или есть более очевидное решение?

Comment: Что интересно, добавляю в /etc/apache2/apache2.conf (Directory /var/www/site/filestorage) php_flag engine 0 (/Directory), перезагружаю сервер, все равно выполняется код в /var/www/site/filestorage/subdir/test.php, хотя сказано что "Устанавливая engine off по необходимости в файле httpd.conf, можно разрешить или запретить интерпретатор PHP"

Comment: Вобщем надо копаться =) каждый раз когда я настраиваю апач своими руками - трачу много времени. Можете поставить xampp на windows, там из коробки много чего работает. И сравнить со своей текущей конфигурацией. И не забывайте перезагружать апач после смены настроек =)

Comment: Что получилось на данный момент: создал еще один VirtualHost (DocumentRoot /var/www/site/filestorage; ServerName site.ru/filestorage, подключил через a2ensite). В /var/www/site/filestorage/.htaccess установил php_flag engine 0. Теперь, если через браузер запустить "плохой файл" с php-скриптом (который злоумышленник загрузил вместо картинки, несмотря на максимальную проверку файлов при загрузке)) ) указав адрес site.ru/filestorage/image/badscript.php, то код в нем не выполнится.

Comment: По причине неполного понимания работы сервера, есть ощущение что это кривое решение, с точки зрения производительности (теперь сервер будет читать конфиги двух хостов, при каждом запросе?), и с точки зрения безопасности (возможно не учитываю еще какие-то способы выполнить вредный код). Как считаете?

Comment: не думаю что тут будет удар по производительности. Для оптимизации лучше поставить связку nginx+apache. Nginx очень быстро отдает статику (картинки, js, css и тд), а для скриптов (php) запускается apache.